# What is the technology for adding a text loader?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know if there's a technology for text loader. I saw this effect on some sites. When the DOM is not fully load there's an effect of loading in the certain text. I want to know if that's a picture, but eventually that will cause the site not to load fast. Or is that a design borders that will be remove on fully loaded DOM.

This is the picture of example:
[image]

Since I can't find the correct way to do it. Just a little bit of idea or insights how to achieve it would be helpful.

Comment: I have seen several implementations using svg with animations

Comment: So basically that's an absolutely position SVG that is going to hide on fully page load? @AivanMonceller

Comment: I think linked in is an example of a site that does this

Answer (score 1):

I  applied that effect using css and css transitions property with javascript. So i think that effect is created with css because some byte of code need to create that effect. so document do not need to load a image file which contains a lot of kb.
Here is my example code for you:

```js
 
function getPost(){
setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo,";
}, 900)}
getPost();
```

```css
#demo .text-plbar1 {
    height: 20px;
    width: 80%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#demo .text-plbar2 {
    height: 20px;
    width: 60%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#demo .text-plbar3 {
    height: 20px;
    width: 40%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#demo .text-plbar4 {
    height: 20px;
    width: 80%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
@keyframes placeHolderShimmer {
            0% {
                background-position: -468px 0
            }
            100% {
                background-position: 468px 0
            }
        }

        .animated-background {
            animation-duration: 1s;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            animation-name: placeHolderShimmer;
            animation-timing-function: linear;
            background: #f6f7f8;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #eeeeee 8%, #dddddd 18%, #eeeeee 33%);
            background-size: 800px 104px;
            height: 96px;
            position: relative;
        }
```

```html
<div id="demo">
<div class="text-plbar1 animated-background"></div>
<div class="text-plbar2 animated-background "></div>
<div class="text-plbar3 animated-background "></div>
<div class="text-plbar4 animated-background "></div>
</div>
```

You can apply this effect using php, ajax, javascript when you fetch data from database;

Comment: Wow. I love the bar animation.